# expresscard 34 mm USB

Tags: expresscard

I buy on amazon this expresscard of 34 mm for my thinkpad t430 just for usb 3.0.
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B00WG9286M/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
How can i find drivers for ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: No additional drivers required.

Comment: i google and notice that the problem was that power management pci exprescard was enabled, when i turn it off, usb is mounted, but when i unplug it, my laptop lags and when i try to plug usb, it does not appear anymore.